# Where to defined code formatting in Xtext

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I am working in project generated by the xtext project wizard.

On the the Internet there is a lot of examples but I cannot see in which project and the package name the code formatting class must be defined.

Must the class also be register?

PS my Java skills is not very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a

```
formatter = {
    generateStub = true
}
```

To the Workflow